# How can I setup a self hosted version of services like LogMeIn and TeamViewer

Tags: logmein, teamviewer, hamachi

Are there any self hosted alternatives to services like Hamachi and LogMeIn or Teamviewer?

Comment: You need to provide us with more info.  Are you using Windows? Mac?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're specifically referring to the fact that these services get around NAT by acting as a directory/junction box, then any VPN is an alternative.  OpenVPN is an example that will provide all the infrastructure for secure networking.  Once connected, you can use remote desktop, vnc, xwindows, etc to do remote control.

Answer (score 1):

[ScreenConnect](http://www.screenconnect.com/Remote-Support) "Self-Hosting provides for ultimate reliability and speed. Reliability is based on the reliability of your own network, not dependent on a 3rd party. Speed is achieved through direct data flow from the remote network to your network."

REFER TO [DUPLICATE QUESTION](https://serverfault.com/questions/258185/self-hosted-desktop-support-remote-control-software-for-windows) ON SERVERVAULT